# Deploy a GitHub branch automatically to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Say I have a branch `stable` on GitHub that I want to automatically deploy to my AWS EB instances when there is a commit.

I have looked at `CodePipeline`, which is not available in the region I am hosting my instances.

I have also looked at `CodeDeploy` but this appears to only be for a single instance of EC2 and not for `Elastic Beanstalk`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

All help is appreciated. I do not want to have to manually deploy every time a commit is made.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: @chemitaxis I have not managed to find an automatic method. I have simply been using the `eb deploy` command from the eb command line utility.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles on this, I would like to comment saying this is possible.

1. You need to create an application on Elastic Beanstalk (This application should be based on the runtime environment of your code for example nodejs for an application built with nodejs, php for a php-application)
2. Make sure to select the sample application provided by aws when creating a beanstalk application.
3. This spins up an environment that runs that sample application (feel free to configure the environment the way you want)
4. Launch the application and then create a new pipeline but be sure to select your source as GitHub in the pipeline (this enables your branch from github to be selected as the source)
5. In the Deploy stage of the pipeline, be sure to select Elastic Beanstalk for deployment.

A well detailed explanation can be found here: https://medium.com/@faithfulanere/how-to-create-cicd-using-github-as-source-and-elastic-beanstalk-244319a2a350

Answer (score 2):

currently we are using jenkins ci for BDD .and jenkins custom [aws-eb plugins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AWSEB+Deployment+Plugin) automatically deploy your branch to elastic beanstalk. this might be help you and even this is the alternative for codepipeline to.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that you can try is use EB Deployer which automates the EB deployments. Here are some helpful links.

https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/ebdeployer-automate-your-deployments-aws-elastic-beanstalk

https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/eb_deployer

Comment: Thank but this seems to have the same functionality as the EC CLI tool which I am currently using.This is fine but I don't want to have to pull a commit from the stable branch, deploy from my local machine and wait for the upload.